# Encrypt and fragment an MP4 file with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, encryption, mp4, decryption

I want to encrypt and fragment an MP4 file with FFmpeg. For this, I use the following command:

```
ffmpeg \
  -i input.mp4 \
  -c copy \
  -encryption_scheme cenc-aes-ctr \
  -encryption_kid 30313233343536373839303132333435 \
  -encryption_key ebdd62f16814d27b68ef122afce4ae3c \
  -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov+default_base_moof \
  output.mp4
```

Trying to decrypt or replay the encrypted file does not work:

```
ffplay \
  -i output.mp4 \
  -decryption_key ebdd62f16814d27b68ef122afce4ae3c
```

FFplay repeatedly outputs the error `saio atom found without saiz`.

When replacing the `-movflags` in the encryption command with `-movflags frag_keyframe`, the first few frame can be decoded (presumably from the first `mdat` box). The error message changes to `Incorrect number of samples in encryption info`. If I remove the `-movflags` entirely (not fragmenting the video), replay works fine.

I'm using version 5.1 of FFmpeg. Is this a known problem of FFmpeg? Can this be fixed?

[I found some people talking about the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44939166/ffmpeg-how-to-produce-mp4-cenc-common-encryption-videos/44949160#comment98574221_44949160) / [similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61912466/simultaneous-fragmentation-and-video-encoding-ffmpeg), but no solutions yet.